# How do the uniform_*_distribution classes in C++ get an equal distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11

I assume that the uniform_*_distribution classes produce a jitter-free equal distribution of all values if the random-generator feeding this classes produces "good" random values. But how does f.e. uniform_int_distribution guarantee a jitter-free equal distribution when feeded by a mt19937_64 ? With my current knowledge I would produce a solution that wouldn't be jitter-free beging feeded by result_type values.

[EDIT]: I have to clarify my wording of a jitter since this seems rather  uncommon for some people here. Jitter means that when you compress or expand a eange through integral division or multiplication, you don't get a clean equal distribution. So there must be another way to to that.

Comment: Your best option is to read the standard library implementations.

Comment: @StephenNewell: Practically yes, but I want to know the way this works.

Comment: Wouldn't reading an actual, tested implementation be the best way to see how it works?

Comment: @StephenNewell: I think there are people here that know it.

Comment: What are you thinking of as “jitter” in this context? It’s not a word that is (IME) applied to PRNGs.

Comment: @Sneftel: Read my edit.

Comment: I think the intended term might be "dither" not "jitter"

Answer (score 3):

By discarding values.

Let's say, as a simple example, that you have a random generator that will give you integers between 0 and 7 (that is, it has a range of 8 values) and you want to use that with a `uniform_int_distribution(0,3)` which is supposed to output 0, 1, or 2 with equal probability.

The naive approach (and the one I think you were considering, given your "jitter" concept) would be to generate a single sample, multiply by 3.0/8.0, and round down. But this would yield 0 and 1 at a higher frequency than 2. And in fact, any approach which sampled the generator exactly once would be guaranteed to be biased, as can easily be demonstrated using the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Generalizations_of_the_pigeonhole_principle).

Instead, the distribution will conditionally throw away *some* values which it gets from the generator, effectively reducing the generator's range to one which it can map to the appropriate distribution. In our example, the distribution could throw away values until it finds one in the range `[0,6)`, and then return that value `mod 3`. So 0 and 3 would map to 0; 1 and 4 would map to 1; 2 and 5 would map to 2; and 6 and 7 would "not count".

[Particularly for continuous distributions, this may or may not be done in a way which leads to exactly unbiased probabilities for each value in the range... and in fact, for some common distributions it would be impossible to do so in a finite amount of time. Nevertheless, that's the basic approach.]

Comment: But with that the output range of the generator would have to be reduced to a common factor with the range I need and thereby in some case I'd skip a lot of values and this could be dementrial for the performance. And the generator needs a value range, larger than the values I need. So this is not a perfect solution.

Comment: Multiple samples can be used when the range of the distribution exceeds that if the generator, of course. As to performance, while it’s not a practical concern, there’s a more complex approach where “extra” entropy is banked and used for future samples; this achieves the optimal performance in terms of number of samples generated.